# Leaflet Geosearch Changing size of the input search

Tags: leaflet

i want to change the size of geosearch on my map

```
const searchControl = new SearchControl({ 
  provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
  style: 'bar',
  notFoundMessage: 'Maaf, Alamat tidak dapat ditemukan',
  searchLabel: 'Masukan alamat',
  showPopup: true,
  updateMap: true,
  draggable: false,
  },
});
mymap.addControl(searchControl);
```

Comment: Inspect the CSS classes applied to the control, then apply your own CSS rules on top of that.

Comment: It didn't work for me, it is a pain in my***